# google endpoint url mapping in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, endpoints, app.yaml

I am following [this example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/getstarted/backend/write_api#coding_a_backend_with_a_simple_http_get_method) but trying to map different url's to different scripts, this example works where the url is simply

```
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
    script: test.api
```

I am trying to map url's with different paths after the default "/_ah/spi/". for eg. test, utils.

```
- url: /_ah/spi/test/.*
    script: test.api

- url: /_ah/spi/utils/.*
    script: utils.api
```

This does not work even with just the one url handler. I get a path not found error.

I cannot find any examples like this and wonder if it is possible to use url mapping like this with google endpoints.

I am trying this on my local dev environment.

Error I am getting is

```
INFO     2016-06-21 10:48:56,273 module.py:788] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO     2016-06-21 10:48:56,274 module.py:788] default: "GET /_ah/api/test/test/v1/simple-test HTTP/1.1" 500 60
```

Endpoint code in test.py is

```
class Message(messages.Message):
    name = messages.StringField(1)

@endpoints.api(name='test', version='v1')
class TestApi(remote.Service):

    """ Simple api test """
    @endpoints.method(
        message_types.VoidMessage,
        Message,
        path='simple-test',
        http_method='GET',
        name='simple-test')
    def simple_test(self, unused_request):
        print("simple-test")
        return Message(name='test simple-test')

#Start the api server
api = endpoints.api_server([TestApi])
```

config in app.yaml is

```
handlers:
- url: /_ah/spi/test/.*
    script: test.api
```

I am using postman and the url is

```
http://localhost:58080/_ah/api/test/test/v1/simple-test
```

---

Comment: I have updated with errors and my code, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer - I didn't use the backend service yet, the answer is based primarily on the documentation, namely [Creating an API Implemented with Multiple Classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#serving_a_multi-class_api)

It seems that multi-class APIs still use a single endpoints mapping in `app.yaml`, corresponding to the collection of all the API classes. From the [app.yaml](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/endpoints/multiapi/app.yaml) file in the [Github example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/endpoints/multiapi):

```
handlers:
# The endpoints handler must be mapped to /_ah/spi.
# Apps send requests to /_ah/api, but the endpoints service handles mapping
# those requests to /_ah/spi.
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: main.api
```

The `/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs` path in the first error you're getting suggests the inability of the backend service to obtain the backend configuration (from which each particular class mapping would be obtained), which would be in line with lacking of this single mapping.

You *might* be able to split your backend classes in multiple files you could use the following approach.

A single/central backend enpoints entry file is specified in `app.yaml`:

```
# The endpoints handler must be mapped to /_ah/spi.
# Apps send requests to /_ah/api, but the endpoints service handles mapping
# those requests to /_ah/spi.
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: backend.api
```

The corresponding `backend.py` file simply collects the actual APIs from other files:

```
import endpoints

from backend1 import api_1
from backend2 import api_2

api = endpoints.api_server([api_1, api_2])
```

And those files contain the respective API implementations (copy/paste'd from the github example and modified slightly for a quick test):

The `backend1.py` file:

```
import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import remote


class Request(messages.Message):
    message = messages.StringField(1)


class Response(messages.Message):
    message = messages.StringField(1)


api_1 = endpoints.api(name='library1', version='v1.0')


@api_1.api_class(resource_name='shelves')
class Shelves1(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(Request, Response, path='list')
    def list(self, request):
        return Response()


# [START books]
@api_1.api_class(resource_name='books', path='books')
class Books1(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(Request, Response, path='bookmark')
    def bookmark(self, request):
        return Response()
```

The `backend2.py` file:

```
import endpoints
from protorpc import messages
from protorpc import remote


class Request(messages.Message):
    message = messages.StringField(1)


class Response(messages.Message):
    message = messages.StringField(1)


api_2 = endpoints.api(name='library2', version='v2.0')


@api_2.api_class(resource_name='shelves')
class Shelves2(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(Request, Response, path='list')
    def list(self, request):
        return Response()


# [START books]
@api_2.api_class(resource_name='books', path='books')
class Books2(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(Request, Response, path='bookmark')
    def bookmark(self, request):
        return Response()
```

With the above code I was able to see the 2 APIs in the development server API explorer:

[image]

Which produced the following logs:

```
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:24,945 module.py:812] default: "GET /_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.pEvOgGtQ_zc.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNv5bf7XiPy_xHPlP3A3K73m3QR2A HTTP/1.1" 200 8015
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:25,058 module.py:812] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 200 5459
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:25,070 module.py:812] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 200 5459
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:25,470 module.py:812] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis HTTP/1.1" 200 1516
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:25,508 module.py:812] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis HTTP/1.1" 200 1516
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:25,813 module.py:812] default: "GET /_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.pEvOgGtQ_zc.O%2Fm%3D__features__%2Fam%3DAQ%2Frt%3Dj%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCNv5bf7XiPy_xHPlP3A3K73m3QR2A HTTP/1.1" 200 8015
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:25,937 module.py:812] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 200 5459
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:25,941 module.py:812] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 200 5459
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:25,942 module.py:812] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 200 5459
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:26,183 module.py:812] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/library2/v2.0/rest HTTP/1.1" 200 3277
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:26,203 module.py:812] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/library1/v1.0/rest HTTP/1.1" 200 3277
INFO     2016-06-21 15:52:26,210 module.py:812] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/library2/v1.0/rest HTTP/1.1" 200 3277
```

Comment: A really elegant solution, this example especially backend.py made it clear on how to use api classes from different files.